# How to Authenticate to LDAP server when the available managerPassword is not in cleartext but hashed using a secure salt?

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

EDIT- The server currently hashes the incoming cleartext user password and compares that with the hash that is stored in the server. My problem is that my application is sending the password already hashed, so when the server tries to hash it again, it obviously doesn't match the cleartext password's hash stored with the server.

An example-

1. Let's assume the password to be **abc** and the hash to be
   **ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad**
2. Normally the LDAP server receives abc as password, computes the hash
   and compares it with what it has stored and it is matched.
3. My Case: Instead of sending abc, I'm now sending it's hashed form
   **ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad**. Now the server hashes this which results in
   **b6291ce396cb2fd46f4a5410b4f9a739ae89e182fc0bd0fc7f8d064e5bfe35e9**, obviously different from the actual hash of abc and the source of my

   problem.

Comment: I don't think I follow it clearly. Instead of receiving a password like `1234` you now receive a hash like `hk6sDPLULZbZRXJTG` and pass it to the LDAP server? If this is the case, the server should expect the password to come hashed instead of plain and the comparison would work fine. It seems to me that you still have to provide the password in plain text.

Comment: Thanks for replying. You assume correct about the change in the nature of the password. My problem is that server is not recognizing the hashed password and only works with the plaintext version. Would the fix involve making some changes in the LDAP server itself?

Comment: I guess so. It seems to me that the server is still expecting the password to be plain text. I think you should check with the team responsible for the ldap server